# How to target an element in a ListView with ShowcaseView in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, showcaseview

I targeted the items in an action bar using `ShowcaseView`, but I can't target elements of a `ListView`! I tried that and it didn't work:

```
ShowcaseView sv = new ShowcaseView.Builder(this,true)
    .setTarget(new ViewTarget(lv.getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.heart)))
    // Here is where you supply the id of the action bar item you
    // want to display
    .setContentTitle("Heart")
    .setContentText("Check the venues of your city")
    .hideOnTouchOutside()
    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Take the element in your `ViewHolder` then place the code for showing the `ShowCaseView` inside your `bindView`.

**Don't forget to put different a different ID for each element in the list.**

So you may try something like this.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  private TextView button;

  public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
          .setTarget(verifyButton)
          .setDismissText("GOT IT")
          .setContentText("Your text goes here")
          .setDelay(100) // optional but starting animations immediately in onCreate can make them choppy
          .singleUse(id + " define an unique id for each item of the list") // provide a unique ID used to ensure it is only shown once
          .show();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

To get more information you can [check the library here](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView).